# Is it possible to do simple division or multiplication in Select Statement? and then insert into new table or create permanent view?

Tags: sql, operator-keyword

I want to calculate the buy/sell ratio based on the two items/values obtained in the select statement, is it possible? Thanks.

```
SELECT Ticker, 
   sum(dBuyAmount) as Buy, 
   sum(dSellAmount) as Sell,
   Buy / Sell as Ratio,
FROM tblQuotation
GROUP BY Ticker
```

Expected Results:

```
Ticker | Buy | Sell | Ratio
APPL   | 2   | 4    | 0.5
MSFT   | 20  | 10   | 1
```

Q2. As I would only store and use the results each day than the original data after running the above SQL statement. The original data will ocassionally be extracted for analysis purpose. 
What if I want to save the above results into a new table or new view for future direct query, as the results above are generated from thousands of data from tbl_Quotation.

I am beginner, sorry for any convenience if the above questions are asked not good enough. Thanks a lot. Welcome feedback and advice.

Comment: use `sum(dBuyAmount)/sum(dSellAmount)`  and it should work

Comment: yes, it works. But is that I could not use the name I assigned to do the calculation? Why I ask this becuase in fact for easy understanding, I have simplified the sum(dBuyAmount), in fact, the orig is sum(case where .... then ....end)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are queries parsed in such a way that disallows the use of column aliases in most clauses?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/why-are-queries-parsed-in-such-a-way-that-disallows-the-use-of-column-aliases-in)

Comment: There are various ways to not reuse an expression (derived table, cte, lateral join/cross apply) although it doesn't necessarily mean that is more efficient to do so, sometimes it may be less. What DBMS are you working with?

Comment: I am using mySQL with Engine: MyISAM. Mainly, I will interact with mySQL with VBA in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74123/8783), a quick way of doing is -

```
---- adjust the decimal places as per your requirement

;with kin_CTE 
as (SELECT Ticker
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN iorder = 1
                THEN Amount
            ELSE 0
            END) AS BuyAmount
    ,sum(CASE 
            WHEN iorder = - 1
                THEN amount
            ELSE 0
            END) AS SellAmount

FROM dbo.Trading
GROUP BY Ticker
)
select Ticker, BuyAmount, SellAmount, convert(decimal(5,1),BuyAmount/SellAmount) as Ratio
 from kin_CTE
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response, while in fact I have second part of the question. after I got the results, is it a good way to save it into a table of the results as I will use the results in the future much more often than the original data in the table. Or I heard of a view, or I shall create a view (permanent?) for it? or I shall run a stored procedure once the market close, say 16:00, the store procedure run itself? is it possible. Thanks a lot.